# Simple example of moving an image (as an animation) in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want load an image in Qt, and move it along the x-axis in an animation.

That's it. I've searched around, but most of the examples are far more complicated than that or use geometric shapes utilizing Qt's drawing functions.

Does anyone here have a link to a sample that just covers my simple use case?

Comment: Check out https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html, it gives a simple example. In your case you want to animate the `x` property rather than `geometry`. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties

Comment: Thank you, looks like the right direction. The example uses "mywidget". In case of an image, what type would I use for that widget? QImage? I am an absolute beginner in Qt.

Comment: The answer depends on how you are using the image. For example, if the image is just part of a UI transition it might make sense to load it into a QPixmap, then set that on a QLabel and animate the label. If you envisage a more complex scene with multiple moving images, you could look at QGraphicsScene. Can you be more specific about the context?

Comment: I will test it at first with one image. QLabel will do I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple implementation with `QTimer`.

Result is:

[image]

So my code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QTimer>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>

class SimpleAnimation : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SimpleAnimation(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QPixmap image(":/0_0.png");
        m_label = new QLabel(this);
        m_label->setPixmap(image);

        QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        mainLayout->addWidget(m_label);

        setLayout(mainLayout);
        m_timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &SimpleAnimation::onTimeout);
        m_timer->start(100);

    }
    ~SimpleAnimation()
    {
    }

protected slots:
    void onTimeout()
    {
        QPoint oldPosition = m_label->pos();
        QPoint newPosition = QPoint(oldPosition.x() + 10, oldPosition.y());

        m_label->move(newPosition);
    }

private:
    QLabel* m_label;
    QTimer* m_timer;

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

When timeout signal emit, we get `QLabel` position, add 10 to x, and move our `QLabel` to new position.

Of couse you can use `QGraphicsScene` for images. Is better for  managing a large number of 2D objects. `QGraphicsScene` is set to `QGraphicsView`, but for one image, it's not necessary.

Comment: Be careful, your class `SimpleAnimation` is memory unsafe!

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou say please where is my mistake ?

Comment: your destructor `~SimpleAnimation` does not `delete` the memory that you dynamically allocate with `new`.

Comment: Additionally, in the `constructor` you allocate dynamically an object `QVBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;`. I guess you should deallocate this before the end of `constructor`! Add `delete mainLayout` before the end of `constructor`

Comment: I add these connections:  `connect(m_timer, &QObject::destroyed, this, &SimpleAnimation::timerDelete);connect(m_label, &QObject::destroyed, this, &SimpleAnimation::timerDelete); connect(mainLayout, &QObject::destroyed, this, &SimpleAnimation::timerDelete);`  to my constructor and  
   `void timerDelete()
    {
          qDebug()<< "timerDelete";
    }` 
slot to check if it deleting or not. It returs me `timerDelete` three times. So all my object destoyed and it has no memory leak

Comment: I am not aware of what `connect` does, but if you handle it, then OK! Although, I think the way you implemented the class is tricky, and will probably be difficult to be reused in the future by someone else, or even yourself!

Comment: @АндреасХаджигеоргиу thanks for advice, you are right, but  i am making a simple example, which a beginner can copy in IDE and see the result . Naturally that in production project programmers makes better designs

Comment: Yes, no worries I understand your intentions! As an addition, I just wanted to point out the potential memory-leaks one could introduce by non-carefully copying this class in their program. To make the post more concise!!!